# mod_rewrite not excluding folder

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, friendly-url

I've setup some rewrite rules to cleanup the URLs of my page. These rewrites work fine, except for some downloads where i don't want to rewrite the URL.

I've tried several Rules to exclude the "files" folder:

1#:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/files[0-9]*/
#Rewrite ulrs:
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?%{QUERY_STRING} [L]
```

2#:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^./files
#Rewrite ulrs:
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?%{QUERY_STRING} [L]
```

3#:

```
RewriteRule ^files - [L]
```

4#:
Putting a new .htaccess file in the "files" folder with

```
RewriteEngine Off
```

Are there any other methods I could try?
I do want to redirect to the pdf download i've setup without rewriting. just like:

```
<a href="files/myDownload.pdf">
```

If I quote the rewrite rule:

```
#RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?%{QUERY_STRING} [L]
```

It no longer rewrites the url and i can access my download, so i just need to get the folder excepted from the rule.

Do you have any Ideas or tips?

Comment: What is exactly wrong with `#4`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All the tries except for #2 should have worked. Please note that the order in which you put your `RewriteRule`s is also very important.

Can you give the following a try:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/files/ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ index.php?%{QUERY_STRING} [L]
```

Comment: I have tried that as well, but sadly it didn't work for me neither.
I'm guessing somewhere else I must have gotten a wrong configuration.
I'll widen my search, maybe there is something else broken.
Thanks though!

Comment: @Cery If you've access to VHost config, enable verbose logging for the rewrite module, and check server logs.